# reset auto_increment with php

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

Why is this code in php not working to reset the auto_increment value to 1?

```
$table="week21";
$sql1 = "ALTER TABLE $table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
$gereset = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
```

Comment: What is the output you're getting from this?

Comment: "ALTER TABLE $table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1"; seems only to work in phpMyAdmin and not in a webpage in php-code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, I had placed the code within a if {} so that the "alter table..." could never be reached.

So this code works now:

```
$sql1 = "ALTER TABLE ".$table." AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
$gereset = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
```

Thanks for the help.